# HOW TO - Applying MCMC to conditionally select random variables?

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, graphical-model, pymc

I am quite new to the using Graphical Models, so pardon me for the naivety. My intention is to have some fun for the weekend and impress my friends on Monday.

I am trying to understand MCMC and Bayesian inference better so that it can be applied to the real world.

Let us say I have a set of nodes. Each node represents a word in English language. based on some data, I have "some" probabilities of words being used together. ("some" -> for the sake of simplicity, assume only co-occurance probabilities of words, n-grams).

Now, I would want to choose a single word from this distribution, which would be conditioned upon some input information (which will also be set of words).

Once I draw this first word, I would want to choose the next word. This word would be conditioned upon the previously selected word and the same input information.

And the process continues. In my understanding, this would be a Markov Chain. For the sake of simplicity, let us assume the length of Markov Chain is always going to be 5.

1. Can this be done using MCMC?
2. Will the probabilities of co-occurance matter or even utilized?
3. Is MCMC good tool for the problem? I think so - because the distribution is going to be huge. There is going to be a high probability of using some words over others. So this kinda falls under exponential distribution family. Then MCMC is a really good toll to do that.
4. Is there any example of something similar available? I was looking at the resources. Almost all of them demonstrate the point using a small toy data, or a small graph of 3-4 nodes. It makes sense to do so, because the intention is to demonstrate the usage of library or conveying the concept. I mean to have, say, one million nodes in the graph, and want it to scale..

Comment: I think you should read up on "Monte Carlo" because MCMC is a Monte Carlo method using a Markov chain. There is nothing in what you are describing that would require the Monte Carlo part of MCMC.